# Cover each line of my code in try catch block

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, exception, try-catch

I have been given a task to implement **error handling** in my app - each and every line of the code has to be checked for error handling. MY friend (who has a background of Java) advised me to put each and every method definition in `try-catch` blocks; which is *not possible* in Swift. As we can put try against only those methods that are **throwable**. So do i need to convert all my methods to throwable and if so, how would i catch exceptions which i am unaware of as that is what we are aiming to achieve. 
So how can i cover my entire project in error handling?

Moreover, I am also doubtful of the fact that does Swift checks for

> "fatal error : Unexpectedly found **nil' exceptions** and **array out
>   of bound exceptions**.

Please, help me through this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can only catch something that can throw error. However, there is no need to catch each and every line of code. If you just creating a variable and assigning some value, there should not be exceptions. Also, it's mostly true that in your code, if some exception happened, the rest of the code should not run. In this situation, you just need a big try catch and inform user when goes wrong in exception handling block.

Swift does not check for force unwrap or index out of bound. It provide you the way to check nil and index using `guard let` or `if let` but you are responsible for this checking.

Comment: Well, I must say Swift then codes for quite ideal scenarios which dont happen in real coding. There must be a provision to put blocks of code in some try catch rather than only on methods that user believes may throw. Developer sometimes may not be considering a scenario that may occur and at that time try catch comes to rescue.

Comment: @Akaanksha Sure, yes you can do that and catch all exceptions. You know how the try catch syntax works, right?

Comment: Yes I do. I was searching something similar to java or .net's try blocks that catches all the exception irrespective of the fact that the methods are throwing or not.